# Как подключиться к виртуальной машине через порт по SSL

Tags: http, ssl, https, gitlab

На виртуальной машине запустил GitLab, устанавливаю внешний URL `http://gitlab.example.com`, пробрасываю порт `55080` на `192.168.88.12:80`, теперь для перехода в GitLab перехожу по ссылке `http://gitlab.example.com:55080`, **все работает**.

Если я меняю URL на `https://gitlab.example.com`, и пробрасываю порт `55443` на `192.168.88.12:443`, то я не могу перейти на сайт, как бы не вводил URL:

- http://gitlab.example.com:55443
- https://gitlab.example.com:55443

> Подключение в локальной сети по https://192.168.88.12 также работает

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: А подключение `https://127.0.0.1` с самой виртуалки работает?

Comment: Да, все работает

Comment: "Пробросили" порт - это в докере? Как установили сертификат `gitlab.example.com`? "Не можете перейти на сайт" - что именно происходит?

Comment: Пробросил порт в роутере, сертификат устанавливается сам, если указать url через https. Когда перехожу на сайт пишет, что не удалось подключиться. Наверное, нужно NAT сделать, а не мост в ВМ?

Comment: "сертификат устанавливается сам" - это как?